# How to set django middleware in settings file

Tags: python, django

Hi all i am trying to add middleware to my app and the app is located in this location

```
myapp/sitemanager/middleware/__init__.py
myapp/sitemanager/middleware/redirects.py
```

what is the right way to declare it in my settings.py file.i currently have it set this way

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ("sitemanager.middleware.redirects.SiteDetectionMiddleware")
```

but i keep geting this error

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware sitemanager.middleware.redirects: "cannot     import name Address"
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that `myapp` and `sitemanager` are actual Python packages (contain `__init__.py`) and in your PYTHONPATH, you may be suffering from a circular import issue.

Comment out all your code in your middleware module and then uncomment your top level imports one by one... just a guess thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd make sure that your Python path is properly configured.
Suppose (in your project) your directory structure resembling this:
Django 1.4

```
/mysite
/mysite/mysite #defult settings.py gonna here...
/mysite/apps
/mysite/apps/__init__.py
/mysite/apps/main
/mysite/apps/main/__init__.py
/mysite/apps/main/models.py
/mysite/apps/main/views.py
/mysite/apps/main/middleware/__init__.py
/mysite/apps/main/middleware/log.py
```

It is my simple midlleware logger exemple (in log.py):

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
import datetime

class Logger(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        f = open('/tmp/log.txt', 'w')            
        f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Note that my custom middleware class (in log.py) is under my middleware python package, that is under *main* app.

So, you should put in your settings.py something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(MY_PROJECT_ROOT)
```

and in middleware tuple:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'...', 
'apps.main.middleware.log.Logger',
)
```

Comment: from your example were is MY_PROJECT_ROOT

Comment: is this what you mean DIR =os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Comment: @user1940979 It's just a common var pointing to your project path such as MY_PROJECT_ROOT = "C:/myprojectdir" or "/home/username/myprojectdir", where myprojectdir is a directory structure created from "django-admin.py startproject myprojectdir" command.