# How to store IP address in the database and django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, ip-address, user-agent

Would like to store IP address of everybody who is coming to the site. What is the best approach to do this. Lets say have model

```
class ip(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

What would be the code in models or in views or somewhere that I would save it in the database also would like to save it with user-agent info similar to this.

[image: django-admin-ip]

Comment: `IPAddressField()` has now [been deprecated](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20439) in favour of `GenericIPAddressField()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In views.py:

**views.py:**

```
    ....

    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')

    if x_forwarded_for:
        ipaddress = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ipaddress = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    get_ip= ip() #imported class from model
    get_ip.ip_address= ipaddress
    get_ip.pub_date = datetime.date.today() #import datetime
    get_ip.save()
```

Comment: great, it is working...is there a way if I create a new field in the model to attach user-agent data? thanks

Comment: I think so. Add a CharField for user-agent data in model class, and views, user-agent data can be get like this: "user_data= request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')" and save it. here is an example:http://pastebin.com/uyHpHxT3

Comment: it works, than you, what are other data about user coming to site that I can store? do you have any idea? thank you

Comment: Welcome. You can look here for other data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: Hello, I just noticed this thing is working perfectly except 1 thing if I am on the page which is password protected for example: "http://www.example.com/accounts/login/?next=/about/" I can see ips in the server logs but it is not logging into the database how to record ip even if you are trying to log in? thank you

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can implement this like: when you call the loginview(lets say it is the class where login mechanism works), in there add the solution code in get request.

Comment: @rentgeeen you can use middleware.it handles every request.

Comment: yes thats what I did I wrote my own, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Worth noting that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` are spoofable headers. OP didn't specify the nature of the application but applications where IP tracking is important it should be used carefully

Comment: @ruddra Shouldn't it be `x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0].strip()` instead of `x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()` as the first ip in the header belongs to the client and not the last? Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 12):

I have gave the example from @Sahil Kalra using middleware,

**Model:**

```
class IpAddress(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    ip_address = models. GenericIPAddressField()
```

**Middleware:**

```
import datetime

class SaveIpAddressMiddleware(object):
    """
        Save the Ip address if does not exist
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        try:
            IpAddress.objects.get(ip_address=ip)
        except IpAddress.DoesNotExist:             #-----Here My Edit
              ip_address = IpAddress(ip_address=ip, pub_date=datetime.datetime.now())
              ip_address.save()
            return None
```

Save the middleware some place in your project folder and In settings file add this middleware. Here is reference [How to set django middleware in settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915209/how-to-set-django-middleware-in-settings-file)

Comment: I am trying to implement it, and its reading all correctly except:  ip_address = IpAddress(ip_address=ip, ip_address=datetime.datetime.now())
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Comment: Sorry I gave the two attributes same name ip_address for pub_date also. I have updated my answer please check it once.

Comment: Now I have error: global name 'BanIpAddress' is not defined - how should I define it or import it? Thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is unintentional mistake BanIpAddress. I have removed this.

Comment: I added your edit and now it says: MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Ip -- it returned 13!

Comment: I gave the above logic because if IP address is there in your db you don't need to add the IP address and if not there you need add the IP address. In this case IP address is unique. `MultipleObjectsReturned` means you added the same IP address in your table. So `get` takes only one object, but in this case multiple objects returned. If you want to get the same IP address use `django orm filter`. If it is useful please accept my answer.

Comment: I did but it stays on the first one when I refresh the page

Comment: What do you want. If you provide more details I will give some logic.

Comment: I adjusted the middleware to record every ip no matter if it was recorded already that pub_date is very important in there. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: +1 for `.strip()`, nobody includes it. It's very important cause in django 1.11 the returned from split is something like ' 123.123.123.123'

Answer (score 6):

You can fetch IP Address very easily into your views.py.

```
def get_ip_address(request):
    """ use requestobject to fetch client machine's IP Address """
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')    ### Real IP address of client Machine
    return ip   


def home(request):
    """ your vies to handle http request """
    ip_address = get_ip_address(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you want to save the user agent irrespective of the URL or View which is being called it **doesn't make any sense** to write this code in the Views or Models.

You should **write a Middleware** that would do the work for you. 
See more about Django middleware : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/

You want to over-ride the `process_request()` method of your custom middleware to get the **IPaddress and useragent from request object** and store it in IP model

The above link will give you absolute clarity about what to do.

Comment: what is the easiest way to save only ip address to database? Thanks

Comment: I am not that advanced programmer, so I would like to know if there is possible to show me on the small example. Thank you