# python django settings perform sql statement

Tags: python, sql, django, variables, settings

I want to define a constant variable in my settings.py file, that will be available in the entire app.
i.e.  if I do in my  settings.py, for example:
VAR = [1,2,3]

then in my view I can access it like:
var = settings.VAR

But, I want that VAR will be fetched from a database.
means, when my app starts, SQL is performed and loads the answer to VAR.

So I've attempted to create a function in views.py that does that:

in views.py:

```
def loadVAR():  
... # perform sql 
return VAR
```

and in settings.py:

```
import myapp.views  
VAR = myapp.views.loadVAR()
```

But it does not work and I get an "500 Internal server error"
I also haven't managed to perform the SQL directly in settings as well.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using middleware before touching the view,

```
class ModelMiddleware(object):
    """
        Model data
    """
    def process_request(self, request):

        # Fetch your data
        # Append var data to request
        request.META['VAR'] = [1, 2, 3]
        return None
```

You can get the VAR in view using request,

```
def veiw_data(request, ):
    print request.META['VAR']
```

Here is [How to set django middleware in settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915209/how-to-set-django-middleware-in-settings-file)

Update:

If you want to call the sql only first time project loads use this way,

I imagined my project structure this way,

```
mysite/
   mysite/
     __init__.py --> Add the logic in this file,
     urls.py
     settings.py
     test.py
   manage.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from catalog.models import Product
import settings

settings.VAR = Product.objects.all()
```

Done. You can access the VAR in your project. Hope this may be helpful

Comment: But isn't that middleware is going to run on EVERY request?  I don't need it to work that way. There is simply some data that I want to have in the server memory, that will be accessible in the app, for every user (unlike session). I need to perform this SQL which pull this data only once, I don't want to perform it for every user.

Comment: Excellent. I've actually never thought using this init.py file (was empty before). but, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

settings.py is not meant to be used that way, if you want to store some settings in a database, consider using some external package which was designed for that, here is [the list](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/) of some of them.

Comment: I don't want to store 'settings' in my database, I need some database  data to be available in my app, and settings.py seems like the only file that has variables that are always available in the app (unlike in views.py - memory cleared after a respone). But I don't mind to create another file for this, that will contain some code and data that will be executed when the app starts, and will not clean until the app is stopped. that is actually what I need.